# How do I gather local user information on the machine with c# .net core

Tags: c#, authentication, console

local operating security boundaries I believe is the correct word usage... im interested in messing around with login information and user accounts. im new to programming but ive been learning fast.

here is my actual question:

I believe System.Permissions is invalid in .net core. With that said, how can I attempt to gather local user information inline with operating system boundaries if i am trying to write a simple console user account application in c#? Further, my ultimate goal with the program is to begin messing around with machine security in combination with browser/online security if that better directs the question I am asking.

Comment: Disregarding the fact "messing around" sounds nefarious, this question lacks a specific problem

Comment: can u direct me to the references in c# .net core that deal with local login information? as well as a reference to operating system security?

Comment: like i said im fairly new so once i direct myself i should be able to start asking more specific questions.